# Grandchild property extracting information of grandfather?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference, access-modifiers

I am in a situation in which I have a class structure similar to this:

```
public class Container {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Entity> Entities {get; set;}
}

public class Entity{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Attribute> Attributes {get; set;}
}

public class Attribute{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public AttributeEnum Type {get; set;}
    public PoisonSpecification Specification {get; set;}
}

public Enum AttributeEnum{
    poisonA,
    poisonB,
    poisonC,
    poisonX
}
```

Every time one adds a new container or modifies an existing Container I perform a validation of the incoming container.

The validation currently starts from the top (container level) to bottom (Typespecifcation)

I am currently in a situation if I see that an Attribute uses type poisonX,  I need to ensure that a specific Entity (specified by the TypeSpecification) exists within the container - but how do I check a container level instance when I am at the TypeSpecification level?

Is somehow possible to reference the parent holding the property - or in this case multiple parents?

Answer (score 0):

do the validation on container level:

```
bool validate( Container c )
{
  foreach( var e in c.Entities )
    foreach( var a in e.Attributes )    
    {
      if (new_or_changed)
        //your validation code
    }
}
```

Comment: the reason why i do it they way I do it is to avoid validating stuff which are the same.. only validate what has been changed or added.  having a double foreloop is performance wise not wanted

Comment: and validate it compared to its oldvalue

Comment: then I suggest to use the double for-loop, but only validate what has been changed or added. this is the fastest way.